# Keen Exact Meaning

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I read this sentence today , and I have some problem for exact meaning of `keen` , Is it equal to `Loves so much` , for example from [here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/BigDaddy):

> Johan is very keen on dogs and other animals.

Is it equal to :

> Johan loves  dogs and other animals so much.

And if they are equal where we should use `keen` instead `Loves so much`.

Comment: Have a look at Oald.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/keen_1?q=keen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Keen** (BrE) and **love** do not mean the same thing.

**Keen** is a British English expression meaning **enthusiasm for** or **looking forward to** or **interest in**

> He was **keen** on getting a new dog as a pet.
>   He was **very keen** to see The Baggies this weekend.
>   She is **keen** to get the house done.

**Keen** can also mean a **an affection for**

> Johan is very **keen** on dogs and other animals
>   He is very **keen** on the new girl in class
>   I'm not so **keen** on malted chips

There are different degrees of **keen**

> **keen**
>   **very keen**
>   **quite keen**

**Keen** is different to **fancy** (BrE), though both mean **attraction towards**.
**Keen** is to **running** where as **fancy** is to **strolling**

> She was peckish and **fancied** a chocolate.
>   He had a hard day at work and was **keen** to get down to the pub.

The differences in describing degrees of interest are

> **Johan is** ***keen on*** **dogs** (BrE)
>   Johan is *interested* in dogs (AmE)
>   Johan is *a big fan* of dogs (AmE)
>
> **Johan** ***fancies*** **dogs** (BrE)
>   **Johan** ***loves*** **dogs** (BrE, AmE)
>   **Johan is a** ***dog-lover*** (BrE, AmE)
>
> **Do you** ***fancy*** **him?** (BrE)
>   Are you *in love* with him? (AmE)
>   Do you have *a crush on* him? (AmE)
>
> **Johan is** ***mad*** **about dogs** (BrE)
>   John is *crazy about / obsessed with* dogs (AmE)

Comment: Excellent answer, although I would like to quibble with one AE equivalency.
Johan is interested in dogs (AmE)  - I would say Johan is a big fan of dogs.   Being a fan of something is more like being keen on it, because it implies a more active participation in liking sometthing.

Comment: "Keen" will be understood by American speakers as well, although you're right that [it's more British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeen%3B%2Cc0) than [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeen%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I can substantiate @stangdon's point. When I first came to grad school in the US and was writing a cover letter with the career services' help, they told me that saying "I am extremely keen to work for your company" is a British thing.